# Socket Programming in C# - The Client Never Connects to the Server

Tags: c#, sockets, localhost

I'm not looking for a complete written solution, I only want to know what is going wrong, as it's part of a school assignment. Both classes are written by the teacher, so I assume something is going wrong on my computer, but I have no idea where to look. I searched for some other solutions and can't find any which is different from this one, except low-level solutions but I also got a low-level solution from my teacher and that also doesn't work.

The server:

```
var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, clientPort);
server.Start();
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient(); // The server gets here
StreamReader clientIn = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
StreamWriter clientOut = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
clientOut.AutoFlush = true;
while (true)
{
    string msg = clientIn.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
    clientOut.WriteLine(msg);  
}
```

The client:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", serverPort); //The client gets here
StreamReader clientIn = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
StreamWriter clientOut = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

clientOut.AutoFlush = true;

while (true)
{
    clientOut.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(clientIn.ReadLine());
}
```

As the client is in a try-catch block, which is in a loop until he has the connection, he tries to connect to the server many times. The server isn't catched, as AcceptTcpClient just waits for a connection, but while they are on the same ip and on the port of the other process, they never reach any connection.

The connections are started in separate threads, but the main thread seems to wait until one is finished, which is not what I expected. I tried to let them both sleep on various methods (with `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, `Thread.Sleep(0)` (documentation said that another thread would be scheduled if you'd do that) and `while(stopwatch<1000ms) {for(i<100000)}`), none of them helped. The main thread only has some progress at the moment that the sleep of the connection-thread is gone and the connection-thread again creates the client.

The problem also arises on another W7 64 bits computer.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Did you tried to make 2 programs (server and client) separate from eachother and what that gives? Also check your firewall of your PC if the connection to that certain port is allowed? And if that is not the problem you can also check if your server application is really started correctly with the following `cmd` command: `netstat -a` and check if the server port is listening there.

Comment: TCP 127.0.0.1:2104 PC_NAME LISTENING. 2104 is the port I'm trying to listen to, so that works correctly. I'll try to make them separate now.

Comment: Two separate programs won't work as well, they give the exact same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem almost certainly resides in the fact that you're using `IPAddress.Any` when building the server. The reason that's an issue is because that will not necessarily resolve to `localhost`, though you may get lucky, it's not consistent. So, I would recommend starting up the server with an IP address like this:

```
var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, clientPort);
```

Next, though I'm confident you're doing this, ensure that the ports are the same for both `clientPort` and `serverPort`.

Next, the `while (true)` loop is very suspect to me so in my example below I'm going to change that. Unless ***impossible*** always avoid `while (true)`, you are literally begging for a problem.

Finally, surrounding how you will do threading here, you're going to need to build two separate threads somehow and I'm going to recommend the `BackgroundWorker` class (others may recommend `async-await` but I don't know enough about it yet to recommend that **and** you would need to be using .NET 4.5 and I don't know if you are).

So, you could build a `BackgroundWorker` like this for the server (and you can build another one similar for the client):

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

worker.ProgressChanged += (s, args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(args.UserState);
}

worker.DoWork += (s, args) =>
{
    // startup the server on localhost
    var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, clientPort);
    server.Start();

    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        // as long as we're not pending a cancellation, let's keep accepting requests
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

        StreamReader clientIn = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        StreamWriter clientOut = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        clientOut.AutoFlush = true;

        while ((string msg = clientIn.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(1, msg);  // this will fire the ProgressChanged event
            clientOut.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, somewhere you'll need to startup these workers by calling `RunWorkerAsync` like this:

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

### Update

Alright, below is a fully working console application connecting on 2104. One thing that you need to note is that when using `var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];` we are getting an IP address that looks like this `::1` and that is the problem. However, if we listen on `127.0.0.1:2104` the client is able to connect because that what it's trying to connect to when issuing `var result = client.BeginConnect("localhost", 2104, null, null);`, which would be the same as issuing `new TcpClient("localhost", 2104);`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

            worker.ProgressChanged += (s, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args.UserState);
            };

            worker.DoWork += (s, args) =>
            {
                // startup the server on localhost 
                var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 2104);
                server.Start();

                while (!worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The server is waiting on {0}:2104...", ipAddress.ToString());

                    // as long as we're not pending a cancellation, let's keep accepting requests 
                    TcpClient attachedClient = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                    StreamReader clientIn = new StreamReader(attachedClient.GetStream());
                    StreamWriter clientOut = new StreamWriter(attachedClient.GetStream());
                    clientOut.AutoFlush = true;

                    string msg;
                    while ((msg = clientIn.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The server received: {0}", msg);
                        clientOut.WriteLine(string.Format("The server replied with: {0}", msg));
                    }
                }
            };

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to establish a connection to the server...");

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var result = client.BeginConnect("localhost", 2104, null, null);

                // give the client 5 seconds to connect
                result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000);

                if (!client.Connected)
                {
                    try { client.EndConnect(result); }
                    catch (SocketException) { }

                    string message = "There was an error connecting to the server ... {0}";

                    if (i == 2) { Console.WriteLine(message, "aborting"); }
                    else { Console.WriteLine(message, "retrying"); }

                    continue;
                }

                break;
            }

            if (client.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The client is connected to the server...");

                StreamReader clientIn = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                StreamWriter clientOut = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

                clientOut.AutoFlush = true;

                string key;
                while ((key = Console.ReadLine()) != string.Empty)
                {
                    clientOut.WriteLine(key);
                    Console.WriteLine(clientIn.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            else { Console.ReadKey(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dns.Resolve is Obsolute, so I changed it in Dns.GetHostEntry, but it didn't solve the problem. I am reall sure about the right ports: I print them and the correspond with the ports on the other console. As the program isn't even reaching the while(true) loops, I won't change it for now.

Comment: @Caution, I've got it working for you. You should be able to look at my code and derive some new things learned from your original example.

Comment: Thanks, that solved part of my problem. I also found another part: I am starting multiple server sockets on the same port, because I didn't thought of doing only one server per port. But that's not part of this question: that is something I can solve without any help.

Comment: @Caution, I'm glad I could be of assistance!